# Dedicated IP vpn for linux

Tags: linux, vpn, web-server, ip, dedicated-server

I have a linux redhat enterprise 5.5 86_6x server inside my network .

My network hasn't dedicated IP and i want to use this server as web server in internet.
can i use a dedicated IP vpn for my linux server to receive traffic from internet?

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, a VPN IP address is private and only works within your VPN. It would **not** work for traffic outside your network.

#### Dynamic DNS

You can use a [dynamic DNS service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) like [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) or [no-ip](http://www.no-ip.com) which will provide you with an domain like yourname.dyndns.org, but they also give other choices (no-ip.com, dnsalias.com, homeip.net).

#### How it works

This pretty much links your dynamic internet IP address to a domain name and when your IP changes, it will updates the domain name to point to that new IP.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to have either a **static IP address** or **dynamic DNS service** for the part of your network that faces the internet so that others in the internet can find you with ease. There are many choices out there; just google it. I use no-ip.com. Most companies offer free service but force to update your host registration once a quarter (or less or more often) or they delete it. Or you can pay $10/year (at No-IP) for getting rid of that bother.
2. Once a request makes it to your network, the router/firewall needs to open the port, or forward it, to the internal IP address (and port) of the web server. This is called **port forwarding**.

That is it. A majority of home router/firewalls can do both of the above with ease.

If you want to segment the web server from the rest of your network you will have to invest in some extra hardware. If, however, you want to do it for zero hardware cost then just pick a port on your router/firewall (I assume you are using a consumer device) assign it an address in your new subnet, update your firewall rules, etc. It is not that complicated but you probably won't be able to do it with the software that comes with most consumer routers. You will have to install OpenWRT or DDWRT or some other similar router OS.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note: what you probably want has been described by Allen and Weboide already.

But it is indeed perfectly possible to set up a VPN to pull a public IP to other places, but it requires having an endpoint with spare IP's routed to/through it and involves some advanced routing tricks on both ends.